# How to describe C# yield return in UML sequence diagram?

Tags: c#, uml, yield

For example,

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class A : IEnumerable
    {
        B b;
        public A()
        {
            b = new B();
        }
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return b.FunA(0);
            yield return b.FunB(1);
            yield return b.FunC(2);
            yield return b.FunD(3);
            yield return b.FunE(4);
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        public int FunA(int x)
        {
            return x;
        }
        public int FunB(int x)
        {
            return x * 2;
        }
        public int FunC(int x)
        {
            return x * 3;
        }
        public int FunD(int x)
        {
            return x * 4;
        }
        public int FunE(int x)
        {
            return x * 5;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new A();
            foreach(var number in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

How to describe this program in sequence diagram?
I think it should be something similar to a loop or alt section like below.

```
              +------------+            +------------+      +------------+
              |  Program   |            |     A      |      |     B      |
              +-----+------+            +------+-----+      +------+-----+
                    |                          |                  |
                    |                          |                  |
                    |                          |                  |
                    |                          |                  |
     +-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+ 
     |loop |        |   [0]                    |                  |       |
     +-----+        |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
     |              |   [1]                    |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
     |              |   [2]                    |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
     |              |   [3]                    |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
     |              |   [4]                    |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     |              |                          |                  |       |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
                    |                          |                  |         
                    |                          |                  |
```

**Edit:**
I'm analyzing the source code of a plugin of Unity3D. IEnumerator and yield are used to implement a coroutine model. The coroutine is used as an alternative to the thread. So it IS reasonable to show the part of the logic of coroutine in the sequence diagram.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't. A sequence diagram is IMHO more appropriate for a sequence of steps of interaction between objects. It doesn't seem that useful to me where the steps are just repetitions of the same action, iterating through a sequence of values.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Maybe it's better to make it clear that I'm reading some codes write in Unity3D. IEnumerator and yield are used to implement a _coroutine_ model. The _coroutine_ is used as an alternative to the thread. So it's not appropriate to say that the steps are just repetitions of the same action

Comment: I'd go with @PeterDuniho. In most cases there is no added value in describing code graphically. SDs should be used for a communication overview. Code is much better to describe algorithms. Reduce the use of regions in SDs to a minimum!

Comment: @ThomasKilian _SDs should be used for a communication overview._ Yes, I mean to explain the source code to someone else and it's important to show the interaction of the classes.

Comment: Interaction of classes is not program logic. You draw a for loop graphically. That's not an overview but a depiction of an algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sequence diagram you can define the loop(while loop) as far as yield keyword execution is concern please refer the below link
[internals of C# interators](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/01/internals-to-c-iterators.html)

I think this link will help you to understand why the yield can be represented as loop.